# List all directories/files I own within the Inode

Tags: unix, inode

I am currently in a class and we are discussing the inode and permissions and brought up a hypothetical situation where you could have ownership of a file without having access to it, and we are trying to discover a way to find such files.  Scrubbing the inode for everything you own would be one way to list out all such elements but the best I was able to come up with was using the command 'ls -laFG' which only looks in the home directory which is not the answer we are looking for.  Does anyone know how to do that, or accomplish something similar?

Answer (score 1):

> "have ownership of a file without having access to it".

Do you mean that the file permissions are 000 (can't read, can't write, can't exec for current user, current user's group and the others) ?

Comment: No, I mean the folder containing the file is currently inaccessible for the owner of a file contained within it.

Comment: So you want to find the files owned by USER whose parent directory is inaccessible for USER ?

Comment: Ok, but what do you mean exactly by inaccessible ? Because if the user has none permission (0) for a folder, you can't access the files within it.

Comment: Correct, that's what my question kind of centers around.  Imagine two users, user1 and user2, if user1 has ownership of a file, they may pass that off to user2, if that file stays in a folder that user1 has access to but user2 does not, when the file is passed off to user2 without the folder access coming as well, then essentially user2 cannot access the file he now has ownership over.